# Web Scraping catching different tags with a initial same name with BeautifulSoup - Issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am tring to catch just de tags "a-price" from a search of the first page results of "iphone" in the Amazon website.

But, the result is including the tags that starts with "a-price", as "a-price a-text-price". How can I ignore this tags by been catched by my scraping code?

Follow the scraping code:

```
s = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features="lxml")
prices = s.find_all("span", attrs={
    "class": "a-price"})
print(prices)
```

Follow the result of the print:

```
[<span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$6.226,87</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">6.226<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">87</span></span></span>, **<span class="a-price a-text-price"** data-a-color="secondary" data-a-size="b" data-a-strike="true"><span class="a-offscreen">R$6.628,98</span><span aria-hidden="true">R$6.628,98</span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$5.099,90</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">5.099<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">90</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$1.460,00</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">1.460<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">00</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price a-text-price" data-a-color="secondary" data-a-size="b" data-a-strike="true"><span class="a-offscreen">R$1.899,00</span><span aria-hidden="true">R$1.899,00</span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$7.488,00</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">7.488<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">00</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$3.874,98</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">3.874<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">98</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$5.899,90</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">5.899<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">90</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$3.499,90</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">3.499<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">90</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$5.222,38</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">5.222<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">38</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$3.299,00</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">3.299<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">00</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$5.661,00</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">5.661<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">00</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$4.788,90</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">4.788<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">90</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$5.999,90</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">5.999<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">90</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$8.974,98</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">8.974<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">98</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$4.117,43</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">4.117<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">43</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price a-text-price" data-a-color="secondary" data-a-size="b" data-a-strike="true"><span class="a-offscreen">R$5.199,00</span><span aria-hidden="true">R$5.199,00</span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$6.935,00</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">6.935<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">00</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$3.058,98</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">3.058<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">98</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$29,90</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">29<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">90</span></span></span>, <span class="a-price a-text-price" data-a-color="secondary" data-a-size="b" data-a-strike="true"><span class="a-offscreen">R$34,89</span><span aria-hidden="true">R$34,89</span></span>]
```

Comment: `[print(t) for t in s.select('[class="a-price-whole"]')]` should do the trick. Or try `[print(p) for p in s.find_all("span", class_ = 'a-price-whole'})]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS selector `[class="a-price"]` to get only tags with class `a-price` and nothing else.

For example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=iphone&__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&ref=nb_sb_noss_2'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, 'lxml')

for t in soup.select('[class="a-price"]'):
    print(t)
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
<span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$6.226,87</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">6.226<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">87</span></span></span>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$1.486,90</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">1.486<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">90</span></span></span>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$7.488,00</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">7.488<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">00</span></span></span>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$3.874,98</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">3.874<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">98</span></span></span>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<span class="a-price" data-a-color="base" data-a-size="l"><span class="a-offscreen">R$3.499,90</span><span aria-hidden="true"><span class="a-price-symbol">R$</span><span class="a-price-whole">3.499<span class="a-price-decimal">,</span></span><span class="a-price-fraction">90</span></span></span>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

... and so on.
```

Comment: Thankz, @andrejkesely!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `class_` argument inside `find_all()` function.

```
s = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, features="lxml")
prices = s.find_all("span", class_ = 'a-price'})
```

Comment: Still not working. Still catching "a-price a-text-price". : /

Comment: @souzalm can you link me the website?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com.br/s?k=iphone&__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&ref=nb_sb_noss_2

Comment: @souzalm use the `find_all('span[class="a-price"]`)

Comment: @souzalm if that is working please upvote my answer and accept it :)

Comment: Now, it´s not catching nothing. "prices" is empty.

Comment: @souzalm try `soup.select('span[class="a-price"]')`

Answer (score 0):

using
`[print(''.join(list(t.stripped_strings))) for t in s.select('[class="a-price-whole"]')]`

gives

`6.226, 1.486, 7.488, 3.874, 3.499, 5.099, 5.222, 3.097, 5.661, 5.899, 8.974, 6.935, 3.058, 29, 2.559,`